# Angular - array updating from promise, integer not updating

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

Currently I have a factory and a controller.  The factory updates with items from an endpoint and the number of pages of data.  My `data` array is being recognized fine, but my `pageCount` (int) update never actually changes.  I have checked to make sure it isn't actually returning 0.

```
.factory('myService', function($http) {
    return {
        data: [],
        update: update,
        pageCount: 0
    };

    function update() {
        return $http.get('path/to/endpoint')
            .then(function(res) {
                angular.copy(res.data.itemsArray, this.data);
                angular.copy(res.data.pageCount, this.pageCount);
                // also tried this.pageCount = res.data.pageCount;
            }.bind(this));
    }
})

.controller('myCtrl', function(myService) {
    myService.update();

    $scope.data = myService.data;
    $scope.pageCount = myService.pageCount;
});

<div>{{pageCount}}</div> // This does not update at all
<div ng-repeat="item in data">{{item}}</div>  // This works fine
```

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, I don't think this a duplicate.  The OP is binding `this` with `bind(this)`.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum could you add why it's a duplicate?  My `this` assignments are working correctly for the array, but not for the primitive.  I didn't see anything in your linked answer about that change.

Comment: @diplosaurus sorry, I missed the `bind`, reopened.

Comment: @diplosaurus can you create a short fiddle (or plnkr) illustrating the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a `promise` with the `update()` function so you can use `then` to handle the result (this will give a more consistent result):

```
.factory('myService', function($http) {

    return {
        update: update
    };

    function update() {
        return $http.get('path/to/endpoint')
            .then(function(res) {
                var result = {
                    data: [],
                    update: update,
                    pageCount: 0
                };

                result.data = res.data.itemsArray;
                result.pageCount = res.data.pageCount;
                return result;
            });
    }
})

.controller('myCtrl', function(myService) {

    $scope.data = [];  

    myService.update().then(function(result) {

        $scope.data = result.data;
        $scope.pageCount = result.pageCount;
    });
});
```

Comment: Not to be pedantic but just so I understand correctly, should `var obj` be `var result`?

Comment: yes. edited.  Thanks, I was half way through writing this answer this morning when the question was closed.  Had to save it in a text file until now. :)

Comment: I tried this out and got a `Provider 'myService' must return a value from $get factory method`.  Presumably because  factory needs to provide a return value.  I tried both changing to a service and setting `this.update` equal to the function and also leaving it a factory and just returning an object with `update: function() {...}` - both of these things caused the browser to hang indefinitely.  I'm wondering if the reference to `update` inside itself is causing an issue.

Comment: @diplosaurus Yes, you must return an object from a factory.  I've made the edit to add back in expose the `update` method.

Answer (score 0):

When you assign the primitive from the service, the reference was lost. Try fetching pageCount from a getter in the service instead. Trying to override the service value is a totally different value to the one in the scope.

It doesn't happen to the array because it's a reference and you used copy.

```
factory('myService', function($http) {
    var pc = 0;
    return {
        data: [],
        update: update,
        pageCount: function() {
            return pc;
        }
    };

    function update() {
        return $http.get('path/to/endpoint')
            .then(function(res) {
                angular.copy(res.data.itemsArray, this.data);
                pc = res.data.pageCount;
            }.bind(this));
    }
})

.controller('myCtrl', 

    function(myService) {
        myService.update();

        $scope.data = myService.data;
        $scope.pageCount = myService.pageCount;
    });

    <div>{{pageCount()}}</div> // This does not update at all
    <div ng-repeat="item in data">{{item}}</div>  // This works fine
```

Comment: below the `angular.copy` in a comment I also tried that assignment with no luck.

Comment: Hey, sorry figured it out. Try my last edit. Be careful using primitives in services

Comment: Surprisingly didn't work...  I tried putting it in a basic object structure and `copy`ing like the array.  Seems odd that that wouldn't work either.